I hit metal inside wooden stud
I'm about to install a new outlet. Whe drilling horizontally through a vertical stud, I hit something metal. The location of the stud very low to the ground, behind my baseboard. This is between two bedrooms and pretty far from a kitchen/bathroom so I doubt it's water or gas pipes. I don't see anything to the left or to the right of the stud. Here's 2 images of my current situation https://imgur.com/gallery/oKxFeOe

metal plates are usually used to protect electrical or water lines

You probably hit one of the nails attaching the bottoms plate to the stud.  You have the drywall off, get down there and shine a light and see what is there. There would be no steel plate IN the stud.

Most walls are built flat on a floor and then raised up.  It makes it easy to hammer nails straight in from the bottom/top plates.  A 3 or 3.5 inch nail will be in the stud ~2 inches.
